# Wordpress returns old thumbnail size after changing media settings

Tags: wordpress, image

I have had a requirement to update a WP build so that the thumbnail size changes from (the default) 150x150 to 500x500.

I've amended the size within the `Settings > Media` and utilised the awesome "Regenerate Thumbnails" plug-in to create the image files at the new sizes. So everything should be cool... alas not!

When I call my new image thumbnail `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'thumbnail');` Wordpress is still returning my image as `...150x150.jpg` and not the new thumbnail size.

I've attempted updating the page/post in which the image appears but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Note: I am using a multi-site instance of Wordpress, but I've checked each instance to ensure that the images have been resized and that the settings have updated. Everything seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Change the resize function to a different tag, i.e. "thumbnail_2". Regen the thumbnails and check to see if the new size reference works **wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'thumbnail_2');**

Comment: This worked for me. If you post it as an answer, I'll give mark it as correct. Would be interested to know the issue at hand though as this seems like a bit of a 'work-around'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the resize function to a different tag, i.e. **"thumbnail_2"**.

Regen the thumbnails and check to see if the new size reference works `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'thumbnail_2');`

**thumbnail** is a WP default term, same as you couldn't (probably) create a custom post type named **post**. Every CMS and framework have defaults that cannot (shouldn't) be overridden. There are many, many reasons for this. It's not a work around, just "the way".